# where are the ftp logs on an centOS machine?

Tags: centos, ftp, logging

where are the ftp logs on an centOS machine?

I am having problem transferring files using filezilla.  I can browse the remote site but can not make a transfer.

```
Error: Could not connect to server
Status: Delaying connection for 5 seconds due to previously failed connection attempt...
Status: Resolving address of callhome4free.webspacecommerce.com
Status: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.100:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Error: Could not connect to server
```

Answer (score 3):

The name of the log file is xferlog, usually it's under /var/log/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using ProFTPD (have to dig since you didn't specify) which puts logs files in the /var/log/proftpd directory if you are using CentOS RPMs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having problems connecting check that FileZilla has "passive" on. These settings are under FileZilla settings | connections.

The error you're getting sounds like it never connects? When you first connect does the fileZilla client ever say "connection Established"?